# Rooting multiple devices

Tags: rooting, root-access, amazon-kindle-fire

let's say I have about 100 old kindle fires to root (or other android devices). Of course I don't want to waste days to root them one by one, is there any way to optimize the process?

Thanks

Comment: Please view this similar question in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/833021/is-there-a-way-to-root-multiple-android-devices-at-the-same-time  (I think this is not an expert solution as the comments on the above link says, just wait for a better solution)

Comment: Write a script to do that, then root them one by one. A huge hub will significantly help the process.

Comment: Thanks, I know for sure that a company has done this, and they need more than 400 devices... I need to set an app as launcher on those tablets, is rooting the only way? In this case I think I'll need a better solution to save me some time

Comment: Otherwise, I could have some people do it for me, but none of my coworkers are... let's say tech friendly, they have never seen a terminal, can I find a more "user friendly" way to make them root the devices?

Answer (score 0):

The first step must be done manually, and one extra tap (confirm a prompt) for each device is required.

1. Enable USB debugging (after unlocking Developer Options) for every device
2. Prepare the files. A custom recovery (you should find it by yourself) and a [SuperSU flashable ZIP](http://www.supersu.com/download)
3. Prepare a script and place the downloaded SuperSU ZIP and recovery IMG in the same directory. Rename the SuperSU ZIP file to `SuperSU.zip` and your recovery image to `recovery.img`
4. Plug in one device and run the script. Tap "Authenticate" if it prompts for USB debugging. It will reboot several times. When the device shows the normal operating system, unplug it
5. Repeat step 4 until all are finished.

Script (Unix version):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "install /sdcard/SuperSU.zip" > openrecoveryscript
echo "cmd reboot" >> openrecoveryscript
adb wait-for-device
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot wait-for-device
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
fastboot boot recovery.img
adb wait-for-device
adb push SuperSU.zip /sdcard/SuperSU.zip
adb push openrecoveryscript /cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript
adb reboot recovery
# You're done!
```